# Memory Hacking/Modifying in C++

Tags: c++, memory

So, I'm trying to write a program in C++, to modify a value in another program. In my case, the Windows' Calculator. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    int nVal = 2000;

    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, "Calculator");
    if(hWnd == 0){
        cerr << "Could not find window." << endl;
    } else {
        DWORD PID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &PID);
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);

        if(!hProc) {
            cerr << "Cannot open process." << endl;
        } else {
            int stat = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)0xC6A0EB922C, &nVal, (DWORD)sizeof(nVal), NULL);

            if(stat > 0){
                clog << "Memory written to process." << endl;
            } else {
                cerr << "Memory couldn't be written to process." << endl;
            }

            CloseHandle(hProc);

            cin.get();

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program tries to overwrite one value, stored with the 'MS' button in the Calculator. The problem is that the program can't do this. I tried to run the executable as administrator, but nothing changes. I found this code on a YouTube video, the guy was using XP, I am using Windows 8.

I found the *0xC6A0EB922C* address using Cheat Engine, and also tried to modify the value inside and it worked perfectly!

If anyone can help me out, please do. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `WriteProcessMemory` is failing, have you used GetLastError to try to find more about why it's failing?

Comment: FWIW, the docs for `WriteProcessMemory` state that it returns non-zero on success and zero on error, not greater than zero on success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Juding from your hardcoded address, your calculator is running as a 64-bit application.

If your program is compiled as 32-bit, the hard coded address `(LPVOID)0xC6A0EB922C` will get truncated to 32-bit and thus be wrong.

To solve this you should either compile your program as 64-bit or use the 32-bit calculator as a test target. It is located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\calc.exe`.

WinAPI functions can fail and they do more ofter than one may want. Always check the return values and call `GetLastError()` if an error occured, so you know why it failed.

Remember to run your program as administrator or turn off UAC when opening other processes.

Comment: Yes! Many thanks, the program works correctly now and writes the number to the Calculator!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what typ1232 said, [ALSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) may also be getting in your way.
Basically, to deter attackers from overwriting hardcoded memory addresses in programs, ALSR will randomize the absolute location in the address space.
I am not 100% sure that calc.exe employs ASLR, as it has to be enabled at compile time (unless you're using tools such as [EMET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2458544))